# Simplest way to Create cross device Location Tracking App (1 app for all)

Tags: cordova, geolocation, location, cross-platform

I've been requested by the boss to make a location tracking app for our internal users. The situation is that they are scattered across different devices including iphone, android and windows phone. I'm over the top of ios and windows phone but relatively new when it comes to the java world of android.

My question is, is there a way to create an app for all devices in one go. I can bang together a html5 app and phonegap it for all, but from what i gather the background process API's are pretty limited and would be a nightmare even if it is doable. If it didn't have to take care of posting geo-location data when the app goes to background i think phonegap would be the go.

Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this? All the app is needed to do is post the Geo data to a web API so its as simple as they come really.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is probably your best bet for a cross-platform solution. The geolocation API will allow you to track geo location on all your target platforms and the relative simplicity of what you need to do means you can hack it up pretty fast.

From what I understand, you need to keeping the app running in the background while the screen is off so geo-location data can continue to be gathered. There are [phonegap plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) for power management for iOS and Android that enable you to do this, though not for Windows Phone AFAIK, but if you're into it you can probably implement the plugin interface without too much trouble. At the point where you start using Phonegap plugins to do native stuff you have to leave the simple beauty of Phonegap Build behind and go down the SDK route for each platform, but that's not the end of the world.

You also mentioned you need to post the geo-data to a web API. Depends where you are in the world, but in my part the mobile phone coverage is patchy so I would go with some sort of offline caching of the data in case an internet connection isn't available right then. Some persistent client-side storage like [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) fits nicely together with Phonegap and would be safer than holding it all in memory. Then you can accrue your data offline and send it all when an internet connection becomes available.